# how to inject different service based on routeParam

Tags: angularjs

Lets say I have to services with similar API but different implementation

```
   myApp.module('myModuleApp').service('BananaService', function(){
       this.name = 'banana';
   });

   myApp.module('myModuleApp').service('AppleService', function(){
       this.name = 'apple';
   });
```

I would like to have a way to inject `Fruit`, and get one of the two services according to a certain routeParam value.

For example, lets assume route `/:fruit/supply`
I would like to have a controller

```
   myApp.module('myModuleApp').controller('FruitSupplyCtrl', function($scope, Fruit, $log){
      $log.info(Fruit.name); // should print banana or apple depends on route
   })
```

What is the pattern in angular I need to use. 
I tried using factory, provider and service, but did not succeed. They are invoked once when the site loads while I need an invocation per route change.

Currently, I have a service Fruit with a method 'get' that simply returns the correct service.

```
   myApp.module('myModuleApp').service('FruitService', function(AppleService, BananaService, $routeParams){
      this.get = function(){
           return $routeParams.fruit === 'banana' ? BananaService : AppleService;
      }
   })
```

but this does not seem right to me. I am sure there is a more `angular way` to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $injector.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector

```
myApp.module('myModuleApp').controller('FruitSupplyCtrl', function($scope, Fruit, $injector){
  var serviceName = Fruit.name + 'Service';
  $injector.get(serviceName);  // this will get the correct service
})
```